# Confusion over Angular4 http inports

Tags: angular, import

I've done a lot of reading on importing http and it only confused me more, so I just decided to follow the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http). But I get the error "to-do.component.ts (4,10) module has no exported member 'HttpClient", and I've found no relevant information when I looked it up, so I'm stuck.

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { GoogleComponent } from './google/google.component';
import { DateTimeComponent } from './date-time/date-time.component';
import { ToDoComponent } from './to-do/to-do.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    GoogleComponent,
    DateTimeComponent,
    ToDoComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

component:

```
//shortened to just imports and the constructor  
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { trigger,state,style,transition,animate,keyframes } from '@angular/animations';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {    

  }
//...
```

It's got to be something simple and obvious, but what could it be?

Comment: You are missing the component decorator unless you withheld it for readability

Comment: I have it, I left it out to make it shorter. I'll add a note saying so

Comment: Also import is an ES6 thing not angular specific thing unless you are talking ngModule import.

Comment: The error you get is cause by code you're not showing us. Post the exact and complete error message, and the relevant code causing this error.

Comment: your formatting broke

Comment: The error is on line 4 of the to-do component, and are the file paths in the error relevant?

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? `HttpClient` only works in 4.3 or higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre issue is either you have somehow lost the npm package for http which means just npm installing it

or

You are using the npm package for angular 2 http which is not in @angular/common/http like it is in angular 4.3+ which means updating it in package.json

Comment: I'm using the CLI v1.4.4 and the http dependency is "^4.2.4", so I need to update. When you say updating it in the json, you mean just changing the version number and it should work?

Comment: http dependency to 4.3+ and npm install or npm update. CLI should not need change.

Comment: "@angular/common": "^4.4.6"  here is a later version but now that I say this I believe you should have all your angular packages on the same version. So my suggestion is to convert all @angular package entries to a consistent version that is >= 4.3

Comment: What is the best way to update all my dependencies? I'm new to npm and don't want to break anything

Comment: `"@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.6",`

just put these in place of the ones you have now

Comment: @Draxy any luck?

Comment: To confirm, I'm just replacing ^4.2.4 with ^4.4.6 in package.json, and it will update? I didn't want to replace the ones I have with yours as mine has things like zone.js and yours dose not.

Comment: Yes that is correct. They should all be able to go from ^4.2.4 to ^4.4.6 without issue. You should do it with anything that starts "@angular/"...

Comment: Thanks so much, re-started ng serve and no errors! Sorry for the noob questions

Comment: Happy to help out.

Comment: For reference for next time, you could use this: https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/. Select 4.3 in the left box and 4.4 in the right box. It then provides you a command similar to what was provided here.